# ¿Por qué me devuelve None esta función recursiva en Python para convertir números decimales en binarios?

Tags: python, binario, decimal

estuve tratando de hacer una función recursiva para hallar un número binario, pero al momento de hacer el return me devuelve None, ¿alguien sabe por qué esta función me devuelve None en Python?

```py
def bina(n, nbin):
    print(n)
    if n == 0:
        nbin = str(0) + nbin
        print(nbin)
        tex = nbin
        return tex
    elif n == 1:
        nbin = str(1) + nbin
        print(nbin)
        tex = nbin
        return tex
    else:
        nbin = str(n%2) + nbin
        print(nbin)
        bina(n // 2, nbin)
n = int(input("convertir a binario: "))
print(bina(n, ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Un cosa que debe revisar en una función recursiva es que **siempre** debe retornar algo, lo que no se cumple en el código original, pues en esta parte se llama a `bina` pero se descarta el resultado.

```
else:
    nbin = str(n%2) + nbin
    print(nbin)
    bina(n // 2, nbin)
```

Reordenando el código para retornar el valor, queda:

```
def bina(n, nbin):
    print(n)
    if n < 2:
        nbin = str(n) + nbin
        tex = nbin
    else:
        nbin = str(n%2) + nbin
        tex = bina(n // 2, nbin)

    return tex
```

También pregunto por `n < 2` en lugar de preguntar si es cero o uno, ya que en ambos casos se ejecuta el mismo código.

**Demo**

```
def bina(n, nbin):
    print(n)
    if n < 2:
        nbin = str(n) + nbin
        tex = nbin
    else:
        nbin = str(n%2) + nbin
        tex = bina(n // 2, nbin)

    return tex

n = int(input("convertir a binario: "))
print(bina(n, ""))
```

produce:

```
convertir a binario: 13
13
6
3
1
1101

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Mejoras

El parámetro `nbin` resulta problemático, pues es realmente para uso interno de la función y su presencia puede confundir al usuario (¿Qué puedo poner en `nbin`?).

Una solución es declarar un valor por omisión apropiado:

```
def bina(n, nbin = ""):
    print(n)
   
    if n < 2:
        nbin = str(n) + nbin
        tex = nbin
    else:
        nbin = str(n%2) + nbin
        tex = bina(n // 2, nbin)

    return tex
```

**Demo**

```
def bina(n, nbin = ""):
    print(n, nbin)

    if n < 2:
        nbin = str(n) + nbin
        tex = nbin
    else:
        nbin = str(n%2) + nbin
        tex = bina(n // 2, nbin)

    return tex

while True:
    n = int(input("convertir a binario: "))
    print(bina(n))
    print()
```

produce:

```
convertir a binario: 13
13 
6 1
3 01
1 101
1101

convertir a binario: 5
5 
2 1
1 01
101
```